# How to reference .so library in visual studio cross platform android project?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mono, shared-libraries

I'm familiar with C# projects, did cross platform development with Xamarin before.

I'm trying to reuse a .so library in a visual studio cross platform android project (Mono C#)? Is this possible?

Don't even know where to start. Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. With Xamarin.Android, you can bundle native libraries into the `.apk`.

To actually call the code, you need to create a `DllImport` function declaration for the existing code to invoke. Everything else is handled by the runtime for you.

```
[DllImport("yourlib.so")]
private static extern int someMethod();
```

Further reading: [Using native libraries](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries/) and [Interop with Native Libraries](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I managed to create a project to run with this SO library. Output log shows found the library and function I was calling alright, but it actually crash out when called. I can't step in when debugging. Is there any way to debug this library in visual studio? Or I have to go back to the owner of this library? Thanks.

Comment: @WinterWinter You could debug C/C++ code using the Microsoft debugger (in Android Options - Packaging tab) but since you don't have the original sources, that's not a viable option. If the error messages from the log don't help you, it's best to go back to the original creator of the library.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @hankide I am referencing a .so (native lib) project in my Xamarin.Android project and using the Microsoft debugger, but not able to debug in to the c++ code, it simply steps over. Do you have any ideas what I may be missing?  Thanks